# Blender how batch import all the objects from my old .blend projects into a new 'Library" project?

Tags: blend-files, append

I know about appending, but it's slow and tedious to go one by one to each old Blender project file looking for objects I like.
I wonder if there's an addon, or some known method for pointing to a folder of old .blend files and saying "import all the mesh objects from these old .blend files into this new project"?
Why? Because I make lots of small little studies, interesting shapes, etc, and now I wish to gather them all up into one project, to create a collection of my objects in one place.

Thanks for any ideas.